# Pandas - Drop lines from dataframe if column value is in list (.csv)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a pandas dataframe imported from SQL, and I would like to drop lines for which a column value is in a list, which I get from a csv file. It seems pretty straighforward, I looked it up and I tried several things using `.isin()` but this is not working as I expect.

For example the dataframe imported from SQL looks like this, let's call it df :

```
    SKU        Brand
0  AD31KL-A1   BrandA
1  BC31KL-B3   BrandB
2  DE31KL-D4   BrandC
3  FG31KL-F5   BrandD
```

I import this list this way :

```
df2 = pd.read_csv("list.csv")
list = df2.apply(lambda x: x.tolist(), axis=1)
```

Let's assume I print the list, this is what I see :

```
[BC31KL-B3]
[DE31KL-D4]
Length: 2, dtype: object
```

Then I use the following :

```
df = df[~df.SKU.isin(list)]
```

I would expect to get this (initial df with lines 1 and 2 dropped because they are in the list)

```
    SKU        Brand
0  AD31KL-A1   BrandA
3  FG31KL-F5   BrandD
```

However this is not what happens. I get the exact same df as initially with no lines dropped, and also no error message of any kind. What am I doing wrong ?
I thought the data in the list and in the df column might not be the same type and I tried fiddling with `astype()`, but without much success. Perhaps i'm using it wrong.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this line is your problem:

```
list = df2.apply(lambda x: x.tolist(), axis=1)
```

The result of a df apply is another df.  Let's say the .csv file has a column called SKU.  You can make a list out of that column only:

```
list = df2['SKU'].tolist()
```

Here's some sample code showing that a  column of values can be converted to a list just by calling `tolist()` on the column/series:

```
# Well, I don't have list.csv, so let me just create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame( ['AD31KL-A1','BC31KL-B3','DE31KL-D4','FG31KL-F5' ], columns = ['SKU'] )
print(df)
list =  df['SKU'].tolist() 
print( list )
```

Here's the df representing list.csv:

```
         SKU
0  AD31KL-A1
1  BC31KL-B3
2  DE31KL-D4
3  FG31KL-F5
```

And here's the list:

```
['AD31KL-A1', 'BC31KL-B3', 'DE31KL-D4', 'FG31KL-F5']
```

Lastly, if you don't have a column name, you can just get the first column by it's integer value thusly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( ['AD31KL-A1','BC31KL-B3','DE31KL-D4','FG31KL-F5' ] )
print(df)
list =  df.iloc[:, 0].tolist()  # first column of dataframe
print( list )
```

Comment: Great, this seems to be working, thanks a lot !
I did not understand that the result of my df.apply was another df rather than a list.